# add scrollbar to figure with subplots

Tags: user-interface, matlab, plot, scrollbar

I have a m-file which should show about 20 images in one figure. so now I would like to know how to add a scrollbar to the figure.

currently, my code is doing something like this:

```
    figure('Name','Results');
for a=1:20
     img_result = imread(userinput);
     %Process image; img_result
     .
     .
     .
     subplot(5,1,a);
     imshow(img_result);
end
```

if i am using this code the images are getting resized to small icons. any ideas?

Comment: How are you going to fit 20 images to 5 subplots? :) Hope it's a typo.

Comment: @Ben: check my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545469/adding-scroll-bar-in-subplots-within-gui/7621402#7621402

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you're looking for: [Scrolling Figure Demo](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5253-scrolling-figure-demo) by [Evan Brooks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/14313)