# building scrolling window with Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am new with the matlab GUI and I am having a problem with creating a window with scrolling.

The problem is as follow:
Lets say I have 100 lines (every line is compounds from several `edit text` and `check box`).

I need that all those 100 lines, will be inside that window - obviously the window is not large enough for all those lines and making the window bigger is not an option - so the trivial solution is scrolling up and down the window and watch all those 100 lines (lets say that the window without scrolling is large enough for 8 lines).
When I tried dynamically to insert more than 8 lines inside that window (normalized `panel`), the new rows makes the rest (older) lines be really small.

[image]

So my question is how can I build "compound" line in a GUI in similarity with strings in "list box"?

Comment: Just to confirm the "matlab-guide" tag; you are using GUIDE right? Would  a programmatic solution be acceptable for you?

Comment: a [`uitable`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) would really be more convenient for such a grid of input field. _They do support checkbox and combobox_ ... and the scrollbar management is built-in with the `uitable`.

Comment: Hi  Benoit_11, yes, a programmatic solution be acceptable for me. thanks

Comment: I have the same question; I am curious if you have found the answer?

Comment: Take a look at [this recent blog post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/scrollable-gui-panels). (Also pinging @Zander)

Comment: Also check the answer to this question, it is all done in pure MATLAB without undocumented code: [Adding scroll bar in subplots within GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621402/3460361)