# Matlab Scrollable Figure

Tags: matlab, scroll, figure

how to make a figure has scroll on it?
my code :

```
f = figure('rend','painters','pos',[100 150 300 150]);

cnames = {'1','2','3'};
rnames = {'1','2','3'};
of=vertcat([2 3 5],[4 5 6],[4 7 1]);
% Create the uitable
t = uitable(f,'Data',of,...
            'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,...
            'Position',[10 100 260 80],...
            'ColumnWidth',{'auto'  'auto'  'auto' 'auto'});
cnames1 = {'A','B','C'};
rnames1 = {'A','B','C'};
of1=vertcat([2 4 1],[4 3 6],[1 7 1]);
% Create the uitable2
t1 = uitable(f,'Data',of1,...
            'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,...
            'Position',[10 0 260 80],...
            'ColumnWidth',{'auto'  'auto'  'auto' 'auto'});
```

I need to add t2, t3, t4,..tn and keep the size of figure on [100 150 300 150]
thank you for your help...best regard

Comment: There is no native way to do that in MATLAB, but there are some way to build it yourself. Very good examples are given here: [Adding scroll bar in subplots within GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7621402/3460361), and here: [Scrolling Figure Demo](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5253-scrolling-figure-demo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding scroll bar in subplots within GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545469/adding-scroll-bar-in-subplots-within-gui)