# Matlab : How to show multiple plots in one single figure with nice navigation like scrolling?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, histogram

I have a large matrix that I compare each column for dependencies. (70 x 70 matrix)I want to show all the correlation plots to be able to interpret data visually. But it seems that matlab provides me a figure with many single lines and I cannot view them clearly. Are there any solutions like scrolling into one figure?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you were attempting and the problem you encountered? It's not clear what "figure with many single lines means".

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122716/add-scrollbar-to-figure-with-subplots, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545469/adding-scroll-bar-in-subplots-within-gui

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Scroll SubPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7730) submission to the file exchange is what you are looking for.